# How to filter string date column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, filter

I have a string date column in the format DD-MMM-YY (EX:29-Jul-18) which is same the filter value. I need to get records which are greater than the given date . But the filter is not working. It's retrieving all the records in the table. The table contains nearly 10M record. Can someone help ?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `date_column` > '20-SEP-22'
```

Comment: You are comparing strings not dates, mysql date format is yyyy-mm-dd, use str_to_date to convert see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date,  Get familiar with the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `date_column` > STR_TO_DATE('20-SEP-22','%d-%M-%y')
```

For more info, please refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

I don't know which programming language you are using, but for maximum query performance, it's better to parse to respective date format before it reaching it to the query that you are supposed to execute. As you said this have million records, so inspect the execution time and choose better solution wisely.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ziyad. I am creating an expression to run the query against the database in a SSIS package. And sure I will check the execution time for the query. Thanks again